# How do I get the raw number of bytes for a PID on Windows CLI?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, tasklist

With lots of research, I've got to this point:

```
tasklist /fi "pid eq 13584" /fo CSV
```

Output:

```
"Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage"
"php.exe","13584","Console","1","25 660 K"
```

It is still an ugly mess. I'm trying to get output such as:

```
25660000
```

That is, no [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or other "formatting"/unwanted data. No "formatted" amount of memory. Just raw bytes.

How is it done?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke this through PHP?

Comment: @ChrisHaas In-deedily-deed I am.

Comment: This involves several steps: executing a command and fetching its output, parsing CSV, parsing a display number in Windows regional settings, parsing the unit suffix... Which one are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0):

Calling some external program and parsing its output is never going to be ideal, but here we go:

```
cmd.exe /D /V:ON /E:ON /c for /F "tokens=2 delims=K:" %a in ('tasklist /fi "pid eq 13584" /fo list^^^|find /i " K"') do @echo.%a
```

This almost works. You still have to remove the space and multiply by 1000, but doing that in PHP is easier than in batch code. It relies a bit too much on how [tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) outputs the data, and this is probably not something you should use in production.

But we can do better:

```
cmd.exe /D /V:OFF /E:ON /c for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %a in ('wmic process where "processid=13584" get WorkingSetSize') do @echo.%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at wmic

wmic process where processid=13584 get WorkingSetSize